# MassTransit hosted service does not implement the synchronous version of disposing (IDisposable)

Tags: masstransit

I am using MassTransit in a ASP.NET Web application hosted in IIS.

It appears that when I stop the application pool, the application is being stopped, Azure Service Bus is stopped but the last thing that is attempted to be stopped - MassTransit.MassTransitHostedService throws an InvalidOperationException.

"'MassTransit.MassTransitHostedService' type only implements IAsyncDisposable. Use DisposeAsync to dispose the container"

StackTrace:
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.SerivceProviderEngineScope.Dispose()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Dispose()

The environment:

1. .NET Framework 4.8.
2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost (Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.2 package)
3. Microsoft DI.
4. IIS 10.
5. MassTransit 8.0.7.

It looks like when the application is shutting down the DI services are disposed synchronously but "MassTransit.MassTransitHostedService" implements only "IAsyncDisposable".

Has anyone encountered such a problem? Is there a way to tell the host to dispose the services asynchronously?

UPDATE 1:

The IWebHost is used from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions v2.2 which is the latest version. That interface derives from "IDisposable" only. Due to some requirements I can't upgrade target framework to 3.0 and above.

Update 2:
Upgrading from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET Core 3.1, usage of "Host" (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) instead of "WebHost" (Microsoft.AspNetCore) fixes the problem.

It looks like WebHost is not able to use asynchronous disposing for MassTransitHostedService.